# react-native run-android throws cannot find certificate

Tags: java, android, react-native, ssl

I am on mac for work, this is a react native project on visual studio code. I only get this error when I npx react-native run-android from vs code or terminal. I tried to go to the gradle website to download gradle. I tried to add a debug keystore to my project. Here is the full errors

EDIT:
Have fixed all errors in React native doctor command, fixed all issues there.

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:130)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:371)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:314)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:309)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:1351)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.onConsumeCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:1226)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:1169)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:396)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:480)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:458)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:201)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:172)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1510)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1425)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:455)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:426)
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:578)
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:187)
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1661)
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1585)
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:224)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:100)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.download(Download.java:80)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:82)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:62)
at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:69)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:62)
at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:107)
at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:63)
```

Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:388)
at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:271)
at java.base/sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:256)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:231)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:132)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:1335)
... 24 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
at java.base/java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:297)
at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:383)
... 29 more
​
error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installQadebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:130)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:371)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:314)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:309)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:1351)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.onConsumeCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:1226)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:1169)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:396)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:480)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:458)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:201)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:172)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1510)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1425)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:455)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:426)
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:578)
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:187)
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1661)
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1585)
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:224)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:100)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.download(Download.java:80)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:82)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:62)
at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:69)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:62)
at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:107)
at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:63)
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:388)
at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:271)
at java.base/sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:256)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:231)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:132)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:1335)
... 24 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
at java.base/java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:297)
at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:383)
... 29 more
​
at makeError (/Users/JWimer/StudioProjects/cw-mobile-react-native-git/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/node_modules/execa/index.js:174:9)
at /Users/JWimer/StudioProjects/cw-mobile-react-native-git/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/node_modules/execa/index.js:278:16
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async runOnAllDevices (/Users/JWimer/StudioProjects/cw-mobile-react-native-git/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/runOnAllDevices.js:109:5)
at async Command.handleAction (/Users/JWimer/StudioProjects/cw-mobile-react-native-git/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js:142:9)

Comment: were you able to solve this?